# Problema con JButton en Java

Tags: java

le he puesto una imagen a mi boton y con setBounds lo he posicionado en la pantalla pero por alguna razon a veces sale bien y a veces el boton ocupa toda la pantalla
Imagenes
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3zfK.jpg
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXrP9.jpg

Porque sucede esto?

```
 public class Ventana extends JFrame {



public Ventana(){

    super("El laberinto");//Establece el nombre de la ventana
    setSize(700, 700);//Establece el tamaño
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//Establece una operacion por deafaul al cerrar
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);//Hace que la pantalla no pueda manipularse de tamaño
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    Fondo f = new Fondo();
    add(f);
    setContentPane(f);
    setLayout(null);
    Botones b = new Botones();


   setContentPane(b.b1v1);
  /*  b.b1v1.setBounds(300,600,50,50);
    setContentPane(b.b1v1);*/





}
public class Juego extends JFrame{


public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    Ventana v = new Ventana();




}

}

public class Botones extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

 ImageIcon ib1v1;
 JButton b1v1;

 public Botones(){

ib1v1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/siguiente.png"));
b1v1 = new JButton(ib1v1);
b1v1.setIcon(ib1v1);

b1v1.setLayout(null);
b1v1.addActionListener(this);
add(b1v1);
b1v1.setLayout(null);
b1v1.setBounds(300,600,50,50);


 }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==b1v1) {
  try{
  Ventana v;
 Ventana2 v2 = new Ventana2();
 v2.setVisible(true);
 v2.setSize(700,700); //Le damos tamaño al frame

 v2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 } catch(Exception excep) {
System.exit(0);
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Algo que te puedo recomendar es siempre dejar de primeras en el constructor la asignación de tamaños y del layout, y de ultimas el setvisible.

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa es que el objeto f es el que establece el fondo de la ventana, olvide poner esa clase, he hecho algo, y fue poner eliminar la clase botones y poner todo su contenido en la clase ventana  y he solucionado el problema, ¿Por qué será? Aun no entiendo pero ha funcionado así.

Comment: Deja setContentPane(f); quita add(f); y cambia setContentPane(b.b1v1); por add(b.b1v1);, setContentPane es para el fondo y solo puede existir un fondo pero con add puedes agregar varios componentes.

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente era eso, aprovecho para preguntar otra duda, sucede que en el evento del botón quiero cerrar la ventana presente y abrir otra, pero no se como cerrar u ocultar la primer ventana pues el codigo se encuentra en la clase botones, intente aplicar:
      this.setVisible(false);
esto lo intente aplicar en el condicional del evento del boton en la clase botones pero obviamente no funciona.

Comment: Si quieres cerrar la ventana debes pasarla como parámetro al constructor de la clase Botones, quedaría algo como Botones botones = new Botones(this), y pues en el constructor pedir un parámetro de tipo Ventana, luego guardas esa ventana que recibes en una variable y ya la puedes usar en el actionPerformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deja `setContentPane(f);` quita `add(f)`; y cambia `setContentPane(b.b1v1);` por `add(b.b1v1);`, setContentPane es para asignar el fondo del Jframe y solo puede existir un fondo pero con add puedes agregar varios componentes al Jframe, si agregas varios fondos se sobrepondrán y solo se vera el ultimo que agregaste.

Comment: Hola tengo un problema aun, por alguna razon no me funciona el setBounds, mi boton sigue en el mismo lugar siempre y no se porque

Comment: Pon la linea  setLayout(null); antes de agregar el boton.

Answer (score 0):

lo único que hice fue, dentro del constructor donde programo las características gráficas de mis componentes, que para este caso sería

```
public Botones()
```

escribes lo siguiente:

```
setLayout(null)
```